# JSP EL causing youtube video to not be displayed

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to display a YouTube video using youtube embed tag and `JSP EL`.

Here is the code.

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="${post.text}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen</iframe>
```

but when I try to hardcode the url like this:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/somevideo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen</iframe>
```

it works fine.

Comment: it means ${post.text} is not getting resolved correctly.

Comment: Why don't you show how the JSP-generated HTML output looks like?

Comment: this is how it looks. thing is that output is the same in both cases.

Comment: `http://` is the difference

Comment: By looking at the output of your `jsp`, its very clear that you need to add `http://` in front of your `${post.text}`